# condition not working, can anyone explain why that is?

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++ so i’m sure there is something obvious about this that i’m missing. I would love it if somebody could enlighten me. thank you!

Im trying to create a loop in c++ that checks the char value of a variable ( it can be any one of these “Y” ,“y”, “N”, “n”), returns an error message if the wrong character is pressed and asks user for new input. If the input is correct, it should continue.

for some reason the error message gets printed even if the input is correct, putting me in an infinite loop.

```
char answer{' '};        // Initialize char with nothing.
std::cin>>answer;        // take user input 

while (answer != 'n' || answer != 'N' || answer != 'Y' || answer != 'y') 
{
    std::cout<<"Error: Please press 'Y' for yes and 'N' for no, followed by 'ENTER'. \n";
    std::cin>>answer;
}
```

Comment: I'd urge you to look at your condition again, in plain language, and think it through, rather than anyone telling you. It should be a pretty clear insight when you get it. Or just do the truth table for the case where answer is 'Y' for example. (This kind of typo-level error is going to happen through your entire career, so get used to writing unit tests.)

Comment: I did a nice write up on this kind of beginner mistake not too long ago with a trick of how to think about loop conditions with AND's/OR's in the future to avoid this. I'd suggest taking a look to help you with this. You can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59546205/2602718

Comment: @KennyOstrom hmm i think see the problem, the while statement executes when any one of the conditions returns true.

Comment: @scohe001 - thank you, i'll take a look!

Comment: Bingo. If it's a correct choice, then it's also not another correct choice. Therefore all correct choices must be errors.

Comment: Recommendation: Now that you've started learning, don't stop. There is always more to be figured out, better idioms to be learned, other languages to steal ideas from...

Comment: Reduce your comparisons by half; see `std::toupper` and `std::tolower`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your Or conditions with And condition.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char answer{' '};
    std::cin>>answer;

    while (answer != 'n' && answer != 'N' && answer != 'Y' && answer != 'y') 
    {
        std::cout<<"Error: Please press 'Y' for yes and 'N' for no, followed by 'ENTER'. \n";
        std::cin>>answer;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you asked nicely :)

Answer (score 3):

Take the expression `answer != 'n' || answer != 'N'`, if you think about it, since `answer` can't be at the same time `'N'` and `'n'` this will always be true, `answer` will allways be different from `'n'` or different from `'N'`. See what I mean?

Answer (score 2):

Change the || to &&. If the char is not 'n' AND the char is not 'N' AND the char is not 'Y' AND the char is not 'y' THEN display the error.

Answer (score 1):

I would had parenthesis:

```
do { 
    std::cin>>answer 
} while ((std::toupper(answer) != 'N') && (std::toupper(answer) != 'Y'));
```

Operators have precedence and it may introduce subtle errors not to mention when using beta compiler.